# How can I replicate between two tables with different names?

Tags: sql-server, schema, replication

While setting up the database replication, the destination table that is getting created is having the same schema name of the source table. I want to have a different destination schema. But how do i get it?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is addressed directly in this [forum post.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreplication/thread/bc709f1c-1cc8-4cde-b9f5-e6babfc649bf)

Snippet:

> ...change destination_table to the new
>   table name in sp_addarticle, or in the
>   wizard, when you get to article
>   dialog, highlight the table, click the
>   Article Properties drop down, and
>   select set properties of highlighted
>   table article, and in the destination
>   object name enter the name of the
>   article.